# AWS CLI for CloudFront create-invalidation returns old invalidation

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront, aws-cli

I'm trying to use the AWS CLI to create invalidations on CloudFront in my CI service to automatically invalidate files on deployment. However, the CLI returns a success message, but the invalidation referenced is a month old and no new invalidation is created.

I'm installing and enabling cloudfront:

```
pip install awscli
aws configure set preview.cloudfront true
aws configure set preview.create-invalidation true
```

Then I create the invalidation:

```
aws cloudfront create-invalidation --cli-input-json '{"DistributionId":"ABC123ABC123","InvalidationBatch":{"Paths":{"Quantity":1,"Items":["/index.html"]},"CallerReference":"codeship"}}'
```

An example of the response, when I ran this command on 7/13 at 4pm ET:

```
{
  "Invalidation": {
    "Status": "Completed",
    "InvalidationBatch": {
      "Paths": {
        "Items": [
          "/index.html"
        ],
        "Quantity": 1
      },
      "CallerReference": "codeship"
    },
    "Id": "1234567890",
    "CreateTime": "2015-06-12T18:39:56.360Z"
  },
  "Location": "https://cloudfront.amazonaws.com/2015-04-17/distribution/ABC123ABC123/invalidation/1234567890"
}
```

When I logged into CloudFront I can see the one invalidation from 6/12, but nothing from yesterday when I ran this command.

Am I doing anything wrong? Does this CLI API even work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like you're passing the same CallerReference for every call to CreateInvalidation? The CallerReference uniquely identifies a particular invalidation request, so CloudFront gives you the result of the first invalidation to use that CallerReference. From the [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/APIReference/InvalidationBatchDatatype.html?r=9424):

> A value that you specify to uniquely identify an invalidation request. CloudFront uses the value to prevent you from accidentally resubmitting an identical request. Whenever you create a new invalidation request, you must specify a new value for CallerReference and change other values in the request as applicable. One way to ensure that the value of CallerReference is unique is to use a timestamp, for example, 20120301090000.
>
> If you make a second invalidation request with the same value for CallerReference, and if the rest of the request is the same, CloudFront doesn't create a new invalidation request. Instead, CloudFront returns information about the invalidation request that you previously created with the same CallerReference.
>
> If CallerReference is a value you already sent in a previous invalidation batch request but the content of any Path is different from the original request, CloudFront returns an InvalidationBatchAlreadyExists error.

Comment: Thank you, that worked great. Guess I should read more carefully :-)

Comment: I had a lot of trouble getting this working, eventually, I used this command (within a package.json file):
`"INVALIDATE": ". .env && aws --profile $PROFILE cloudfront create-invalidation --distribution-id $AWS_CLOUDFRONT_DISTRIBUTION --invalidation-batch '{\"Paths\":{\"Quantity\":1,\"Items\":[\"/*\"]},\"CallerReference\":\"my-invalidation-'$(date +%s)'\"}'"`. Note how the `$(date +%s)` function needs to be wrapped in `' '` so that it is not processed as a string. Hopefully others can find this helpful